# php connection to mysql with multiple users

Tags: php, mysql, security

Recently i ve been trying to make a web application with user management. Different users, with their passwords will be able to register, login, etc...

I also made a mechanism, which will ban ips for some time, if something not allowed is happening. These ips are stored in a mysql table, in the same database with the other site data.

My question is, is it normal to make it so, that in the beginning of the script, php would query the database using mysql user A (for example), to see if this ip is banned and if not then proceed to query for the rest of the site data making a new connection with the database using mysql user B credentials.

Is it overkill? Would it be lighter if the banned ips were logged in another database?

Or perhaps query a file with the banned ips? I don't suppose they will be too many at the same time, but i prefer to rely on mysql's caching system than doing all this I/O for every script (heavy ajax using site).

I thought of storing them in ram using memcached, but then they would require encryption, so i don't know if that would be faster.

I suppose you could tell me to benchmark them and see which is lighter, but if someone has any idea, or done this before, why reinventing the wheel? :p anyway thank you :)

Comment: Your text is hard to read. Read this "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem": http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Comment: tried to edit. hope it's more readable now

Comment: You need ban "IP by user" or only "IP"?

Comment: i need to ban IPs that either are logged in users or just non authorized viewers of the site. So I need to ban plain IP

Comment: Why would you need to use two different MySQL users?  Why, if using memcached, would you need to encrypt a stored IP?

Comment: @Klimid1689 If I understand, you want to know the best way for block IPs, in other words, store in mysql ou `I/O` ("files"), taking into account ease of block and unblocking management, performance and security (I mean the efficiency in blocking), am I right?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento yes